# BASH loop through multiple files replacing content and filename

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm trying to find all files with a .pux extension 1 level below my parent directory. Once the files are identified, I want to add a carriage return to each line inside each file (if possible, only if that line doesn't already have the CR). Finally I want to rename the extension to .pun ensuring there is no .pux left behind.

I've been trying different methods with this and my biggest problem is that I cannot develop or debug this code easily as I cannot access the command line directly. I can't access the Linux server that the script will run on. I can only call it from my application on my windows server (trust me, I'm thinking exactly what you are right now).

The Linux server is running BASH 3.2.57(2). I don't believe the Unix2Dos utility is installed as I've tried using it in it's most basic form with no success. I've confirmed my find command can successfully identify the files I need as I have ran this and checked my log file output.

```
#!/bin/bash
MYSCRIPTS=${0%/*}
PARENTDIR=/home/clnt/parent/
LOGFILE="$MYSCRIPTS"/PUX2PUN.log

find "$PARENTDIR" -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -type f -name "*.pux" > "$LOGFILE"
```

Logfile output:

```
/home/clnt/parent/z3y/prz3y.pux
/home/clnt/parent/wsl/prwsl.pux
```

However when I have tried to build on this code and pipe those results to a while read do, it doesn't appear to do anything.

```
#!/bin/bash
MYSCRIPTS=${0%/*}
PARENTDIR=/home/clnt/parent/
LOGFILE="$MYSCRIPTS"/PUX2PUN.log

find "$PARENTDIR" -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -type f -name "*.pux" -print0 | while IFS= read -r file; do
    sed -i '/\r/! s/$/\r/' "${file}" &&
    mv "${file}" "${file/%pux/pun}" >> "$LOGFILE"
    done
```

I'm open to other methods if they are standard in my BASH version and safe. Below my parent first should be anywhere from 1-250 folders max and each of those children folders can have up to 1 pr*.pux file each (* will match the folder name as shown in my example output earlier). So were' not dealing with a ton of files.

Comment: Add `-d ''` option in `read`

Comment: Well, SOB. Looks like that did it. Thank you @anubhava. I've been banging my head on this code for over a day.